# OpenVPN does not see TAP Adapter

Tags: windows, tap, openvpn

I have OpenVPN-server running on Windows Server 2008R2 via 1194 UDP Port. Most of the clients are connected well but 2 machines cannot (WinServer 2008 and Win7 Pro). The error is:

```
Thu Nov 07 11:54:57 2013 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Thu Nov 07 11:54:57 2013 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

The TAP-Win32 Adapter status is "Cable unplugged" while I'm trying to connect. The same TLS key negotiation failed error occurs when I remove TAP adapter or turn it off in Windows control panel (Seems like OpenVPN is not connecting to TAP). The firewall is turned off, UDP 1194 is open. 
I've tried to explicitly set the tap adapter name by adding dev-node AdapterName in config file without any result.

The problem's probably not in the network, because I have 2 machines successfully connected to VPN within the same local network. The listing of client config file is:

```
tls-client  
proto udp
remote <server ip address here>
dev tap
dev-node myTap
pull
tls-auth c:\\vpnkeys\\ta.key
ca c:\\vpnkeys\\ca.crt
cert c:\\vpnkeys\\client30.crt
key c:\\vpnkeys\\client30.key
cipher DES-EDE3-CBC
comp-lzo
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was an unproperly configured network. OpenVPN is not using tap adapter until it gets response from remote host.